# Getting error trying to access list of injected instances (playframework/scala/guice)

Tags: java, scala, playframework, guice, scalatest

I have an api service that have WSClient dependency and Configuration dependency:

```
Class MyApiService @Inject() (wsclient: WSClient, conf: Configuration) {...}
```

Now I have some animal objects that depend on this api:

```
Class Lion @Inject() (myApiService: MyApiService) extends Animal {...}
```

And I have another class `AnimalActions` that needs the instance of the animal objects and perform some actions with it.

So I careated a trait to help me do that:

```
trait AnimalObjects {

  def application: Application

  def animalList = List(classOf[Lion],
                       classOf[Tiger])

  lazy val animalInstances: List[Animal] = animalList.map(animal => application.injector.instanceOf(animal))
}
```

so now I can go:

```
class AnimalActions @Inject() (val application: Application) extends AnimalObjects {...}
```

and in `AnimalActions` I have access to `animalInstances`...

Thing is, when I test this and just try to access animalInstances I get an error, I go:

```
class MyTest extends FreeSpec with OneAppPerSuite {

  val animalActions: AnimalActions = app.injector.instanceOf[AnimalActions]

  "AnimalActions Test" in {
    println(animalActions.animalInstances)
  }

}
```

And the error I get is:

> 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NumberFormatException: null 
>   at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider.(AhcWSModule.scala:40)
>   at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider.class(AhcWSModule.scala:39)
>   while locating play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AsyncHttpClientProvider   while
>   locating play.shaded.ahc.org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClient
>       for the 1st parameter of play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientProvider.(AhcWSModule.scala:203)
>   at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientProvider.class(AhcWSModule.scala:203) 
>   while locating play.api.libs.ws.ahc.AhcWSClientProvider   while
>   locating play.api.libs.ws.WSClient
>       for the 1st parameter of services.MyApiService.(MyApiService.scala:21)   at
>   services.MyApiService.class(MyApiService.scala:21)   while locating
>   services.MyApiService
>       for the 1st parameter of animals.objects.Lion.(Lion.scala:19)
>       Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

I could of swear that it worked before, not sure whats up with that :/

thanks